# Querying Laravel Relationship

Tags: eloquent, laravel-5, relationship

I am trying to get one query work since morning and not able to get it working I have two tables photographers and reviews please have a look at structure and then I will ask the question at the bottom :

Reviews table :

```
id int(10) unsigned -> primary key 
review text
user_id int(10) unsigned foreign key to users table
user_name varchar(64) 
photographer_id int(10) unsigned foreign key to photographers table
```

Photographers table :

```
id int(10) unsigned -> primary key
name text
brand text
description text
photo text
logo text
featured varchar(255)
```

Photographers model :

```
class Photographer extends Model
{

public function reviews()
{
    return $this->hasMany('\App\Review');
}
}
```

Reviews Model :

```
class Review extends Model
{
public function photographers()
{
    return $this->belongsTo('\App\Photographer');
}
}
```

My logic to query the records

```
$response = Photographer::with(['reviews' => function($q)
{
    $q->selectRaw('max(id) as id, review, user_id, user_name, photographer_id');
        }])
        ->where('featured', '=', 'Yes')
        ->get();
```

The question is : I want to fetch all the photographers who have at least one review in the review table, also I want to fetch only one review which is the most latest, I may have more than one review for a photographer but I want only one.

Comment: it's not relevant to the answer of this question, but i would rename the `Review::photographers` method to Review::`photographer`, as it is a "belongs to" relationship, and will only ever return a single result. (semantics)

Answer (score 1):

I would add another relationship method to your Photogrpaher class:

```
public function latestReview()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Review')->latest();
}
```

Then you can call:

```
Photographer::has('latestReview')->with('latestReview')->get();
```

#### Notes:

- The `latest()` method on the query builder is a shortcut for `orderBy('created_at', 'desc')`. You can override the column it uses by passing an argument - `->latest('updated_at')`
- The `with` method loads in the latest review.
- The `has` method only queries photographers that have at least one item of the specified relationship

Have a look at [Has Queries in Eloquent](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations). If you want to customise the has query further, the `whereHas` method would be very useful

#### If you're interested

You can add query methods to the result of a relationship method. The relationship objects have a query builder object that they pass any methods that do not exist on themselves to, so you can use the relationships as a query builder for that relationship.

The advantage of adding query scopes / parameters within a relationship method on an Eloquent ORM model is that they are :

- [cacheable (see dynamic properties)](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations)
- [eager/lazy-loadable](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#eager-loading)
- [`has`-queryable](http://laravel.com/docs/5.0/eloquent#querying-relations)

Answer (score 0):

What you need is best accomplished by a scoped query on your `reviews` relation.

Add this to your Review model:

```php
use Illuminate\Database\Query\Builder;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Review extends Model {
    public function scopeLatest(Builder $query) {
        // note: you can use the timestamp date for the last edited review,
        // or use "id" instead. Both should work, but have different uses.
        return $query->orderBy("updated_at", "desc")->first();
    }
}
```

Then just query as such:

```php
$photographers = Photographer::has("reviews");
foreach ($photographers as $photographer) {
    var_dump($photographer->reviews()->latest());
}
```

Comment: it says Call to undefined method Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection::latest()

Comment: `->reviews` should be `->reviews()`, my bad.

Comment: i think you need to call `get()` after `has` to execute the query (if you're doing what i think you're doing). and possibly after `latest()`

Comment: (I should probably note I'm not actually testing this in any way, as I don't have access to my dev environment)